# How can i bind a value to a label from database which is inside header template?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Kindly Give me some suggesstions what i can do to achieve this result.
I want to bind a label (which is inside the header) by database as employee designation may change as per the requirement.
I have tried by rowbound but its dosent work

```
<asp:GridView ID="Gridview2" runat="server" Width="99%" GridLines="Both"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>

                <tr class="header1">
                    <th colspan="2">
                        <asp:Label run="server" ID="labeldesignation" Text='<%# Eval("designation") %>'>Designation</asp:Label></th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="header2">
                    <th>Emp_Id</th>
                    <th>Emp_Name</th>
                </tr>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td><%# Eval("Emp_Id") %></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("Emp_Name") %></td>

                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the Label using `FindControl` in the `HeaderRow`.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the row is a datarow
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //cast the row back to a datarowview
        DataRowView row = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

        //choose from which row you want the data into the header
        if (e.Row.RowIndex == 4)
        {
            Label lbl = ((GridView)sender).HeaderRow.FindControl("labeldesignation") as Label;
            lbl.Text = row["designation"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

PS a GridView generates it's own `<tr>` and `<td>` tags. Don't put your own in the templates. Check the html of a simple GridView and see what html it generates.

Answer (score 0):

Do it on the back on page_Load

set the value of label

```
this.labeldesignation.Text = dataset[0].column[0].toString();
```

I will assume that you use DataTable instead Dataset.

Add another table to pull out consist the parts of your table in UI (Gridview)
Like Header, footer, pages something like that.